# C# WPF Hacer un datatable con 2 objetos

Tags: c#, wpf

Hola lo que quiero hacer es un datatable como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo pensado una estructura como esta:

```
public class Inventario {
    public string Material { get; set; }
    public double Cantidad_Inv { get; set; }
}

public class Cliente {
    public string Nombre_Cliente { get; set; }
    public List<Pedido> Pedido { get; set; } = new List<Pedido>();
}

public class Pedido {
    public string Material { get; set; }
    public double Cantidad_Pedido { get; set; }
}
```

Datos de la tabla:

```
        var inv = new List<Inventario>() {
            new Inventario(){ Material = "Papa", Cantidad_Inv = 100},
            new Inventario(){ Material = "Uva", Cantidad_Inv = 50}
        };

        var clientes = new List<Cliente>() {
            new Cliente(){
                Nombre_Cliente = "Cliente1",
                Pedido = new List<Pedido>(){
                    new Pedido(){ Material = "Papa", Cantidad_Pedido = 30},
                    new Pedido(){ Material = "Uva", Cantidad_Pedido = 20}
                }
            },
            new Cliente(){
                Nombre_Cliente = "Cliente2",
                Pedido = new List<Pedido>(){
                    new Pedido(){ Material = "Papa", Cantidad_Pedido = 70},
                    new Pedido(){ Material = "Uva", Cantidad_Pedido = 30}
                }
            },
        };
```

Como le puedo hacer para meter esa información en una tabla en xaml?

Gracias

Comment: Cuál es tu pregunta, o en qué necesitas te ayudemos?

Comment: Hola en crear la tabla, como seria en xaml?